# Occasional 500 error

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

We use Apache+mod_wsgi to host our Django application.

Apache:

`WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rls/django_wsgi.py`

django_wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('data/misc/django')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'rls.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Everything works fine, but occasionally we get 500 Internal Server Error with this in the logs:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4825): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/rls/django_wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 33, in load_middleware
for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
self._setup()
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'rls.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named rls.settings
```

Of course there are no syntax errors in settings.py since it loads fine every other time. What I'm missing? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Normally one shouldn't see this randomly unless you simply haven't restarted Apache or mod_wsgi daemon processes since last change to configuration in Python code.Post relevant parts of Apache configuration file for setup of mod_wsgi, including how you are using VirtualHosts, indicating whether you have multiple VirtualHost definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the absolute path to the directory that contains the file settings.py.
In your case should be something like:

```
sys.path.append('/%s/data/misc/django'%ROOT_2_DATA)
```

You must also check that apache group has permissions to read/write the folder.

Comment: Yep, i noticed that / was missing almost right away after posting this question, and it does fix the problem. I dont know why it worked at all though, since the path was wrong. Thanks for your answer.